# How can I create a Python module or class that returns by cycling all the values in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, class, module

I'm trying to create a module / class that cycles all the values of a list or table.
If I have a list and I would like to create a module that at each iteration gives me the value following a variable.
Type with a for in loop.

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

# for i in list:
#     print(i)

def reader(list):
    for i in list:
        return i

while True:
    var = reader(list)
    print(var)
```

The result I would like to achieve is that the module gives me the following value of the list at each cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is generator which will give you each value of one at a time. following reader will give you the result

```py
def reader(list):
    for i in list:
        yield i
```

Same result can be obtained by generator expression

```py
reader = (i for i in list)
```

you can use it like this

```py
for i in reader:
   print(i)
```

Comment: Wow is the right solution, and if I want to transform the list in a Dictionary? Like{'a': 1, 'b': 2 etc.}

Answer (score 0):

You can set a class variable to an index value for the item you wish to be printed and update it with a separate function that returns the values as per the following.

```
class Cycle:

  def __init__(self, cyclable_list):
    self.index = 0
    self.cycle_list = cyclable_list

  def returnValue(self):
    value = self.cycle_list[self.index]
    self.index = (self.index+1) % len(self.cycle_list)
    return value
```

When running the following code, the cycle object would return each value on the list in order before restarting from index 0.

```
cyclable_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
my_cycle = Cycle(cyclable_list)

for i in range(7):
  print(my_cycle.returnValue())
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
```

And so forth...

Comment: I only partially solve the problem, in a larger context I must then evaluate the values and compare them.
In practice, if I had to read a database table I would then have the possibility to iterate the object.